# Swift Extension of Array with Equatable Elements Cannot Call Index(of:)

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-extensions

I am attempting to add an extension to the Array type in Swift limited to Arrays whose elements conform to the equatable protocol. I am attempting to define a function in the following manner:

```
import Foundation

extension Array where Iterator.Element: Equatable {

    func deletedIndicies<T: Equatable>(newArray: [T]) -> [Int] {

        var indicies = [Int]()

        for element in self {

              if newArray.index(of: element) == nil {

                     indicies.append(self.index(of: element)!)
              }
        }

        return indicies
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of the function is to return the indices of any items in the original array that do not appear in the `newArray`.

The error I receive in Xcode is: Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: Element)'

Since I am defining the function for only Arrays whose elements are equatable and am requiring that the elements of the `newArray` are equatable, I am unsure why I cannot invoke the index method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're defining a new generic placeholder `T` in your method – which is not necessarily the same type as `Element`. Therefore when you say `newArray.index(of: element)`, you're trying to pass an `Element` into a argument of type `T`.

The solution therefore is to simply to type the `newArray:` parameter as `[Element]`:

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    func deletedIndicies(byKeeping elementsToKeep: [Element]) -> [Int] {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As a side note, this method could also be implemented as:

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {

    func deletedIndicies(byKeeping elementsToKeep: [Element]) -> [Int] {

        // use flatMap(_:) to iterate over a sequence of pairs of elements with indices,
        // returning the index of the element, if elementsToKeep doesn't contains it,
        // or nil otherwise, in which case flatMap(_:) will filter it out.
        return self.enumerated().flatMap {
            elementsToKeep.contains($1) ? nil : $0
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you change the constraint on `Element` to `Hashable`, this could be also be implemented in O(n), rather than O(n * m) time, which could potentially be desirable:

```
extension Array where Element : Hashable {

    func deletedIndicies(byKeeping elementsToKeep: [Element]) -> [Int] {

        // create new set of elements to keep.
        let setOfElementsToKeep = Set(elementsToKeep)

        return self.enumerated().flatMap {
            setOfElementsToKeep.contains($1) ? nil : $0
        }
    }
}
```