# Generic Array Extension for symmetricDifference

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, set-difference

I wrote this function to get the difference between two arrays of strings.

```
func difference<T:Hashable>(array1: [T] ,array2:[T]) ->[T]? {
   let set1 = Set<T>(array1)
   let set2 = Set<T>(array2)
   let intersection = set1.symmetricDifference(set2)
   return Array(intersection)
}
```

Now I want to extend it to a generic function for different types like `Int`, `Double` etc...

```
extension  Array where Element: Hashable {
   func difference<T:Hashable>(array2: [T]) -> [T] {
      let set1 = Set(self)
      let set2 = Set(array2)
      let intersection = set1.symmetricDifference(set2)
      return Array(intersection)
  }
}
```

With this extension, I get the error:

```
Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred.
```

I tried different approaches but in vain.
What could be the problem?

Comment: You're defining a new generic placeholder `T` for your method, which is not necessarily the same type as `Element`. Just use a parameter and return type of `[Element]` – see for example [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41045212/2976878).

Comment: `func symmetricDifference(to array: [Element]) -> [Element] {` or `func symmetricDifference(to array: Array) -> Array {`

Comment: I think that would be better to return a Set instead of an Array: `extension Array where Element: Hashable   {
    func symmetricDifference(to array: Array) -> Set<Element> {
        return Set(self).symmetricDifference(array)
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly as @Hamish mentioned in his comment above, you're extending `Array` with one type and trying to execute the `symmetricDifference` with an another type (`T: Hashable`) that the compiler cannot infer.

You can fix it returning an `[Element]` and use it the same type as argument in the function, something like this:

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {

   func difference(array2: [Element]) -> [Element] {
      let set1 = Set(self)
      let set2 = Set(array2)
      let intersection = set1.symmetricDifference(set2)
      return Array(intersection)
   }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: You can also just use `Array` instead of `[Element]`

Comment: `extension Array where Element: Hashable   {
    func symmetricDifference(to array: Array) -> Array {
        return Array(Set(self).symmetricDifference(array))
    }
}` no need to make the second array a set

Comment: thanks for all the answers and explanations. I think i have still much to learn about generics!